# How to extend logging without aggressively modifying code? [Write clean code]

Tags: python, design-patterns, coding-style

Let's say I have a `calculate()` method which have complicated calculation with many variables, while I want to log down what is the value of variables in different phase (EDIT: Not only for verification but for data study purpose). For example.

```
# These assignment are arbitrary, 
# but my calculate() method is more complex
def calculate(a, b):
  c = 2*a+b
  d = a-b
  if c > d+10:
    g = another_calc(a, c):
  else:
    g = another_calc(a, d):
  return c, d, g

def another_calc(a, c_d):
  e = a+c_d
  f = a*c_d
  g = e+f
  return g
```

You may assume the method will be modified a lot for experimental exploration.
There is no much logging here and I want to log down what happen, for example I can write aggressive code like this

```
# These assignment are arbitrary, 
# but my calculate() method is more complex
def calculate(a, b):
  info = {"a": a, "b": b}
  c = 2*a+b
  d = a-b
  info["c"], info["d"] = c, d
  if c > d+10:
    info["switch"] = "entered c"
    g, info = another_calc(a, c, info):
  else:
    info["switch"] = "entered d"
    g, info = another_calc(a, d, info):
  return c, d, g, info

def another_calc(a, c_d, info):
  e = a+c_d
  f = a*c_d
  g = e+f
  info["e"], info["f"], info["g"] = e, f, g
  return g, info
```

This serve my purpose (I got the info object, then it will be exported as CSV for my further study)
But it is pretty ugly to add more (non-functional) lines to the original clean `calculate()` method, changing signature and return value.

**But can I write a cleaner code?**
I am thinking whether it is possible to use decorator to wrap this method. Hope you guys would have some great answers. Thanks.

Comment: I would just using `logging.info` to print the relevant information to stdout. Your code runs sequentially I guess, so there should not be any trouble to read and understand the output. Alternatively you can use a good debugger to inspect each variable value in each single step without logging.

Comment: Do you have any idea how many references there are to calculate() method? Is it inside a class? Usually, in similar cases, I have tried to first make simple unit tests to understand input/outputs and then refactored the logic support new features. If you add a parameter to the method, it should not be a problem, if you also have default value because then the change of method signature not break usage/references. If you just declare info -dictionary inside calculate() then calculate() have new dependency and can cause problems. Also, returning new values from a function can break things.

Comment: Thanks for your answers
@DariusMorawiec. As a data science project actually, I want to export them into a csv format, with different columns as different variables information, so that I can analyze them. If it is free-text log, I would need to do much parsing work.

Comment: @T.Nylund I have 2 * 20+ reference I want to log, and most of them are local variables. Yes I can write unit test to test the feature but I would like to export actual value of parameters for further study. I agree that the `info` dict is very ugly and it is my current (working) solution, so I seek people's help to see how to write it clean

Comment: Thanks. I send my answer according to given information. Maybe you can get new ideas when trying it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to write cleaner code (my opinion) is to wrap the info -dictionary inside a class.

Here is my simple code example:

```py
# These assignment are arbitrary, 
# but my calculate() method is more complex
def calculate(a, b, logger):
  logger.log("a", a)
  logger.log("b", b)

  c = 2*a+b
  d = a-b

  logger.log("c", c)
  logger.log("d", d)

  if c > d+10:
    logger.log("switch", "entered c")
    g = another_calc(a, c)
  else:
    logger.log("switch", "entered d")
    g = another_calc(a, d)

  return c, d, g

def another_calc(a, c_d, logger):
  e = a+c_d
  f = a*c_d
  g = e+f
  logger.log("e", e)
  logger.log("f", f)
  logger.log("g", g)
  return g

class Logger(object):

  data = []

  def log(self, key, value):
    self.data.append({key: value})

  def getLog(self):
    return self.data


logger = Logger()
print(calculate(4, 7, logger))
print(logger.getLog())
```

## Pros and cons

I use separated logger class here because then I don't need to know how the logger is implemented. In the example, it is just a simple dictionary but if needed, you can just change the implementation of creating a new logger.

Also, you have a way to choose how to print the data or choose output. Maybe you can have an interface for Logger.

I used a dictionary because it looked like you was just needing key-value pairs.

Now, using the logger, we need to change method signature. Of course, you can define default value as None, for example. Then None value should be checked all the time but that is why I didn't define the default value. If you own the code and can change every reference for the `calculate()`method, then it should not be a problem.

There is also one interesting thing that could be important later. When you have debugged your output and not need to log anything anymore, then you can just implement [Null object](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object/python/1). Using `Null object`, you can just remove all logging without changing the code again.

I was trying to think how to use decorator but now find any good way. If only output should be logged, then decorator could work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understood and agreed most of your points, and found the null object way interesting .However, it is still aggressively inserted many non-core logging code to the method, compared with the original no logging method (13lines vs 23lines). I am afraid it will force developers to read extra code which he don't really needed. I can think of decorator, aspect-oriented programming (but difficult to use in my case). Hope you guys have other ideas.